# Probability of passing exams

Tags: probability

This question came in my exam and I had no clue how to do it:

> *If the probability that a student passes a math exam is $0.7$, the probability of passing a physics exam is $0.6$, and the probability of passing the math exam but not the physics exam is $0.3$, what is the probability of passing neither exams?*

I tried to use the formula $P(A∪B)=P(A)+P(B)−P(A∩B)$ ,but it didn't work.

How would I go about it?

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram and label the regions with their meanings and probabilities. Then the formula to use will suggest itself.

Comment: @EthanBolker , I could use Venn diagram , but I find it sometimes confusing to me specially when there are multiple events.

Comment: can you try the alternative $P(A∪B)=P(A\setminus B)+P(B\setminus A)+P(A\cap B)$?

Comment: @RahulMadhavan , what does the notation $P(A \ B)$ , is it conditional probability ? we haven't studied conditional probability yet , how to solve it without it ?

Comment: $A\setminus B$ refers to a set of elements in A but not in B. For example, you could consider $P\setminus M$ as probability of passing Physics, but not maths exam.

Comment: @RahulMadhavan , I can't see how this helps to find $P( A ^ c \cap B ^ c)$ , and how to find $P(A \cap B)$ ? , could you please give me the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event of passing the math exam and $B$ the event of passing the physics exam. First note that, since
$$P(A) = P(A \cap B^c) + P(A \cap B),$$
we get
$$P(A \cap B) = P(A) - P(A \cap B^c) = 0.7 - 0.3 = 0.4$$
Now using De Morgan's laws we get that
\begin{align*} P(A^c \cap B^c) &= 1-P(A \cup B) \\
&= 1-(P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)) \\
&=1- (0.7+0.6 - 0.4) \\
&= 0.1
\end{align*}